# Data table to SQL table losing precision

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have a datatable with values consists of more than 12 decimal places (e.g. `451234.123456789012`) that I'm fetching from an Excel sheet. I'm inserting the values from datatable to SQL table using user-defined table.

In my stored procedure I have a statement like,

```
insert into tblMytable(fld1, fld2..)
Select fld1, fld2,.. from @MyUDT
```

Issues:

1. Suppose all the Excel cell type is 'General' I'm getting the full precision in the data table but when I'm inserting this to SQL table I'm losing all except 2 precisions.
2. Suppose all the Excel cell type is 'Text' I'm getting only 12 digits for the entire value including Non decimal. Decimal part. e.g. For `451234.123456789012`, I'm getting `451234.12345` in my C# datatable. And the same I'm getting after inserting to SQL table.

In my UDT the fields are defined as `varchar(20)`, I checked with `varchar(45)` but no use.

Comment: Is your data table converting them to Decimal with 18 character precision?  Or is the data table all string?

Comment: @Ted, I'm usig oledbDataAdaptor to fill the excell to datatable, i'm not doing any conversion.

Comment: What datatype are those columns in your database? Also: you say *SQL* (Structured Query Langauge) - but you really mean **SQL Server** - the Microsoft RDBMS - right??

Comment: What is the data-type in the `DataTable` ? And how are you reading the data from Excel? What is the data *as you fetch it* from Excel? Personally, I suspect the issue here is at the *reader* end, overenthusiastically treating it as decimal/double.

Comment: 1. Suppose all the uploaded Excel cell types are 'General' I'm getting the full precision in the C# data table. Then i'll insert this C# datatable to SQL server 2008 table using UDT, that time i'm getting only 2 precisions. But all the excel cell types are Text in the c# datatable itself i'm getting only 12 digits including decimal and non  decimal digits. I can change the uploaded cells type programatically.

Comment: @Wilz: You need to change your SQL server Table column DataType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have handled the issue using,

Since I'm getting the full precision while reading the excel type as general to the C# datatable, I created a datatable clone by changing the column type alone as string, so that I'll get the values all string type as well as with full precision, then i'm passing the datatable to SQL 2008 table without losing the precision, now its working fine.

Code:

```
dt= ds.Tables[0].Clone();
for (ICol = 0; ICol < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; ICol++)
    dt.Columns[ICol].DataType = typeof(string);
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows) 
    {
        dt.ImportRow(row); 
}
```